# Service Account in Multiple Organizations

Tags: google-chat-api

I want to create google-chat bot.
There is a question on how one service account works in multiple organizations chat.

As far as I understand service account gets token and may execute API calls in any organization, where chat-bot was added. Am I right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you do an API call to fetch chats(spaces), how will it know which organization to fetch the chats from?